# Matrix to CSV in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, dictionary, matrix, reduce

Writing an MxN matrix ( M rows, N columns ) to a CSV file:

My first attempt, using map, works, but creates N references to the stringbuffer. It also writes an unnecessary comma at the end of each row.

```
def matrix2csv(matrix:List[List[Double]], filename: String ) = {
  val pw = new PrintWriter( filename )
  val COMMA = ","

  matrix.map( row => {
    val sbuf = new StringBuffer  
    row.map( elt => sbuf.append( elt ).append( COMMA ))
    pw.println(sbuf)
  })
  pw.flush
  pw.close
}
```

My second attempt, using reduce, also works but looks clunky:

```
def matrix2csv(matrix:List[List[Double]], filename: String ) = {
  val pw = new PrintWriter( filename )
  val COMMA = ","

  matrix.map( row => {
    val sbuf = new StringBuffer  
    val last = row.reduce( (a,b)=> {
      sbuf.append(a).append(COMMA)
      b
    })
    sbuf.append(last)
    pw.println(sbuf)
  })
  pw.flush
  pw.close
}
```

Any suggestions on a more concise and idiomatic approach ? Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the 2nd attempt to compile? In `sbuf.append(b)`, there's no `b` in scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can obtain the string representation easily:

```
val csvString = matrix.map{ _.mkString(", ") }.mkString("\n")
```

Then you just need to dump it in a file.

Pay attention to end-lines (here "\n" ), they vary according to the platform.

Comment: Thanks, that's very concise & idiomatic.

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatically, you're misusing `map` by using it to perform side-effecting operations. You should use `foreach` for this instead.

This is what it could look like if you used a `foreach` and replaced your `StringBuffer` boilerplate with a call to the `mkString` method:

```
def matrix2csv(matrix:List[List[Double]], filename: String) {
  val pw = new PrintWriter(filename)
  val COMMA = ","
  matrix.foreach { row => pw.println(row mkString COMMA) }
  pw.flush
  pw.close
}
```

Note that `mkString` uses a `StringBuilder` (a non-thread-safe `StringBuffer`, which is fine here).